# OBIEE not able to connect with Mongo Database

Tags: mongodb, odbc, obiee

After upgrading Mongo database version 4.4 to version 6 ,All our OBIEE reports are failed and While doing View data in RPD for Mongo Database tables also I’m getting the following error(I can able to import the tables using mongo connection pool) so can you please help me out.

**While running report I’m getting below error.**

```
Odbc driver returned an error (SQLExecDirectW).
```

Error Details
Error Codes: OPR4ONWY:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:U9IM8TAC:OI2DL65P
State: HY000. Code: 10058. [NQODBC] [SQL_STATE: HY000] [nQSError: 10058] A general error has occurred. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 43113. [nQSError: 43113] Message returned from OBIS. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 43119. [nQSError: 43119] Query Failed: (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 16001. [nQSError: 16001] ODBC error state: 37000 code: 1064 message: [MySQL][ODBC 1.4(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.14.12]parse sql 'select distinct T690657."PROGRAM" as c1 from "DATALAKE_CANONICAL" T690657' error: syntax error: unexpected STRING at position 34 near PROGRAM. (HY000)
State: HY000. Code: 16002. [nQSError: 16002] Cannot obtain number of columns for the query result. (HY000)
SQL Issued: SELECT 0 s_0, "medwProcess"."DIM_DL"."PROGRAM" s_1 FROM "medwProcess" FETCH FIRST 100000001 ROWS ONLY

**
While viewing the data using the RPD in Offline mode,I’m getting error like below.**

[nQSError:16015] SQL Statement execution failed.
[nQSError:16001] ODBC error state :37000 code:1064 messages
[mySQL][ODBC 1.4(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.14.12]parse sql 'select count(distinct "Scoringflag") from "datalake_canonical"
error: Syntax error: Unexpected STRING at position 63 near datalake_canonical

i have tried to import the metadata using the connection pool ,its working but while viewing the data using the same connection pool it's throwing an error.

Comment: It would help if you provided an exact version number for the OBIEE you're working on.